# Selecting data from sql to create a thumbnail

Tags: php, templates, resultset

I'm creating a thumbnail with a title, image and caption on it. I'm trying to select data from my table to show it into my homepage. Can someone help me to create a normal thumbnail in my php that contains the detail from my sql. I tried to search and can't find how to create a thumbnail using php and not html.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>id</th>";
                echo "<th>first_name</th>";
                echo "<th>last_name</th>";
                echo "<th>email</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['caption'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

In short, is there a way to create a php file from this?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img alt="Memory" img src="../../images/a2.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3><b>
                Title
            </b></h3>
            <p>
                Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption
            </p>
            <p align="right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="news2.html">Read More</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you mean by thumbnail using PHP, anyway you will be using the HTML tags. PHP help to retrieve the information and you need the HTML to structure it properly. Are you storing the image URL in your DB?

Comment: @Kuru Yes i stored the image url in my database but it only shows the url but not the image, I already edit the question, what I'm trying to say is if theres a way i can transfer that html file to php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to replace your table structure with that template structure?  You'll need to adjust some of the data to fill the hyperlink (I don't know how you want to build that).

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
        echo "<div class=\"thumbnail\">";
            echo "<img alt=\"Memory\" src=\"../../images/{$row["image"]}\">";
            echo "<div class=\"caption\">";
                echo "<h3>{$row["title"]}</h3>";
                echo "<p>{$row["caption"]}</p>";
                echo "<p align=\"right\">";
                    echo "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"news2.html\">Read More</a>";
                echo "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: @JayDoe I am not entirely clear on what you want to create.  If this is not it, please leave a comment to clarify.

Comment: @mickemackusa for the clarification. `echo "<h3>{$row["title"]}</h3>";` and `echo"<h3>{$row['title']}</h3>";` any difference?

Comment: @Kuru no, both are the same.  Use single quotes if you like.

Comment: @mickemackusa Normally i use like this `echo"<h3>$row['title']</h3>";` (without curly brackets) so when i saw your code i thought it might raise syntax error then i notice the curly bracket, so i just need to clarify that one... that's all

Comment: @Kuru Yes, that is just my default coding style.  Your way is perfectly valid.

Comment: @mickmackusa i tried your script and it works, but there is one problem. How can i link the "Read More" button to different html file? E.g. Thumbnail #2 should link to news3.html and not just html2

Comment: @JayDoe you can add another column to your database table that stores the appropriate link for the row.  Then just drop `$row['link']` into that space.  Or if this was my project, I'd probably use one static file/page and append `?id=3` then you can avoid adding another column to your db table, just use the ids.  Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @mickmackusa I create another column "newsupdate" and add the url of my file, but when I tried to click the "Read More" button a message prompt that Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

Comment: @JayDoe You will need to show me what you've done.  You can use https://pastebin.com/ to store your code online (remove any sensitive data) and send me the link and I'll have a look for you.

Comment: @JayDoe Add a space before `href`.  There is no escaped double quote `\"`between href and the variable.  Is the variable a valid url?  Only you can check that part.